# How to move multiple items from one listbox to another in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I am trying to move multiple items from one list box to another. I can select multiple items in one listbox but only move them one at a time. I have tried creating a list of multiple selected items but was wandering whether there is something built in for this? any help appreciated-code is below

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

my_window = Tk()

my_frame_in = Frame(my_window)
my_frame_in.grid(row=0, column=0)
my_frame_out = Frame(my_window)
my_frame_out.grid(row=0, column=1)

listbox_events = Listbox(my_frame_in, height='5', selectmode=EXTENDED)
listbox_events.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
listbox_events_filtered = Listbox(my_frame_out, height='5', selectmode=EXTENDED)
listbox_events_filtered.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=(0, 10), pady=10)
my_instructions = Label(my_window, text='Use arrow keys to move selected items')
my_instructions.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=(0, 10))

my_list_events = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

for item in my_list_events:
    listbox_events.insert(END, item)


def select_events(event=None):
    listbox_events_filtered.insert(END, listbox_events.get(ANCHOR))
    listbox_events.delete(ANCHOR)

def deselect_events(event=None):
    listbox_events.insert(END, listbox_events_filtered.get(ANCHOR))
    listbox_events_filtered.delete(ANCHOR)
# ref https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm


listbox_events.bind('<Right>', select_events)
listbox_events_filtered.bind('<Left>', deselect_events)


mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the selected items in the first list box and insert them into the second listbox. I have updated your code to show this.

```
from tkinter import *

my_window = Tk()

my_frame_in = Frame(my_window)
my_frame_in.grid(row=0, column=0)
my_frame_out = Frame(my_window)
my_frame_out.grid(row=0, column=1)

listbox_events = Listbox(my_frame_in, height='5', selectmode=EXTENDED)
listbox_events.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
listbox_events_filtered = Listbox(my_frame_out, height='5', selectmode=EXTENDED)
listbox_events_filtered.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=(0, 10), pady=10)
my_instructions = Label(my_window, text='Use arrow keys to move selected items')
my_instructions.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=(0, 10))

my_list_events = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

for item in my_list_events:
    listbox_events.insert(END, item)


def move_items(event):
    if event.keysym == 'Right':
        src_list = listbox_events
        dst_list = listbox_events_filtered
    elif event.keysym == 'Left':
        src_list = listbox_events_filtered
        dst_list = listbox_events
    else:
        return

    for _item in src_list.curselection():
        dst_list.insert(END, src_list.get(_item))

    for _item in reversed(src_list.curselection()):
        src_list.delete(_item)


listbox_events.bind('<Right>', move_items)
listbox_events_filtered.bind('<Left>', move_items)


mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that! is the reversed(src_list.curselection()) the same as dst_list.curselection()?

Comment: @Sid, no the are different, reversed(src_list.curselection()) is listbox 1 and the second is dst_list.curselection() listbox2